ssh-agent empty through ssh remote session
My scenario
I have a linux machine (fedora workstation 39) for development, I have java, node, podman, IDE's, everything works as expected. For git I setup keys (to clone using ssh) and gpg (signature).
Issue
I bought i mac studio m1, and I want continue to use linux. for that I'm using intellij ssh remote

it works.
The problem is git, the ssh-agent is empty from the mac side (through ssh)

But inside fedora is accessible.

How make mac "see" the ssh-agent?
